# There is a closed hyperplane.

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

$\textbf{Question: }$ If $M$ is an open convex set in normed linear space $R$ and $x_{0}\not\in M$, then there exists a closed hyperplane which passes through the point $x_{0}$ and does not intersect $M$.

My try: I know every open set contains its interior point so $I(M)$ is not empty.(of course we assume $M$ is not empty). So, M is convex body. Then , Minkowsky functional $P_{M}(x)$=inf{$r$: $\dfrac {x}{r}\in M $ $ r>0$} is convex and finite. Then what do i need to use Hahn Banach ?. How can I go closed hyperplane ?

Thanks in advance any help.

Comment: I think you have a typo. If $x_0 \in M$, and the plane passes through $x_0$, then it must intersect $M$.

Comment: oh sorry $x_{0}$ is not element of $M$ can you edit please ? I couldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One version of the Hahn Banach separation theorem states that in a real topological space, if $A,B$ are non-empty disjoint convex sets, and $A$ is open, then there is some constant $\lambda$ and a continuous linear functional $f$ such that $f(a) < \lambda \le f(b)$ for all $a \in A, b \in $.

Here $A=M, B= \{x_0\}$, and since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1} \{ x_0 \}$ is a closed hyperplane that does not intersect $M$.

Comment: But how $B=${$x_{0}$}  can be convex set ? That is the point I couldn't say directly or am I thinking to complicated ? otherwise , it is ok. I know this theorem.

Comment: How do you define convex?

Comment: M is convex whenever it contains two points x and y, it also contains the segment joining x and y.

Comment: There is no requirement that it contains two points. The only requirement is that if $x,y \in C$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then $\lambda x + (1-\lambda )y \in C$. In the case of $C = \{x_0\}$, this condition is trivially satisfied, hence it is convex.

Comment: Ok, now i realized the theorem that i know is not continuous, instead it says there exists a nontrivial linear functional f. That is why, I had a trouble to solve.